# C# Replacing escaped escapes

Tags: c#, string, arraylist

Ive parsed a text file into a `List<string>` object and the test file contains `\n` and `\t`, however once I output the strings to console they appear as "\n" and "\t" rather than a new line and a tab.

At the moment i'm using `myList[i].Replace(@"\n", "\n").Replace(@"\t", "\t")` but this seems a little cumbersome, especially if more escape sequences need to be added in the future.

Is their any way to un-escape the escaped sequences? Something like `string.UnEscape` would be just to perfect.

Comment: Am I right that test file keep `\n` and `\t` as text?

Comment: @sll yes, plain text document written in notepad

Comment: Are you sure that the escape sequences in your text file will always match *exactly* the escape sequences used by C#? If not, you are better of writing your own `Unescape` method.

Comment: @Heinzi Yup, i'm writing the test files.

Comment: Ok how are you parsed a file?

Comment: @sll Using `StreamReader.ReadLine()` and from there the strings get split up a bit before being stored in a `List<string>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will do exactly what you're after but there is an [`Unescape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape.aspx) method in the `RegEx` namespace.

```
string result = Regex.Unescape(myList[i]);
```

Comment: Watch out for this issue... 

If the Unescape method encounters other escape sequences that it cannot convert, such as \w or \s, it throws an ArgumentException.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, I did come across it but thought it was only for use with regex's, guess I should have read the documentation better

Answer (score 3):

You could write your own helper..

```
 public static class Helper
    {
        public static string Unescape(this string val)
        {
            return val.Replace(@"\n", "\n").Replace(@"\t", "\t");
        }
    }
```